# change subpanel names in ggplot Predict

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used a multivariable regression model to explore the relationship between variables.

```
model<- lrm(mortality ~value_day0 + value_day5, dataframe, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

Then to visualise:

```
plot_model<- ggplot(Predict(model, fun=plogis), sepdiscrete="vertical", ylab="risk of mortality")
```

This gives me the graph with 2 subplots/ subpanels, 1 for the day 0 value and 1 for the day 5 value. How do I change the names of these subpanels? Currently, they have the name of the variable (value_day0 and value_day5), but I want to change this, without having to change the variable name in the dataframe.

Some sample data

```
dataframe<-data.frame(mortality=rep(c(0,1), each=500), value_day0=sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE), 
               value_day5=sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

thanks!

EDIT:

```
ddist <- datadist(value_day0, value_day5, mortality)
options(datadist='ddist')
detach(dataframe)
```

Comment: When running your sample data and code, the Predict call throws an error. You may want to confirm that your example runs correctly?

Comment: hi @xilliam, I added some code to my question that probably solves the error! Sorry forgot to add to earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'plot_model' object includes a data.frame with a variable named '.predictor.', which holds the facet labels. You can change the facet labels with `factor()`, and `facet_grid()` does the rest with it's `labeller = label_value` default setting:

```
library(rms)
library(ggplot2)

dataframe <- data.frame(mortality=rep(c(0,1), each=500), value_day0=sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE),value_day5=sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE))

ddist <- datadist(dataframe)
options(datadist='ddist')

model<- lrm(mortality ~value_day0 + value_day5, dataframe, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)

plot_model<- ggplot(Predict(model, fun=plogis), sepdiscrete="vertical", ylab="risk of mortality")

# this code changes the changes the labels on the '.predictor.' variable.
plot_model$data$.predictor. <- factor(plot_model$data$.predictor., labels = c("Day 0", "Day 5"))

#  this 'label_value' labeller() call alters the facet labels
plot_model + facet_grid(. ~ .predictor., labeller = "label_value")
```